# Bootstrap popover top-right corner always on top

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

How can I make my popover display in the top-right corner of the page, without it being connected with an arrow to the button, kind of like a popup? Should I use something else than a popover?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Help" data-toggle="popover"  data-content="423241421453453"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="font-size: 20px; padding-top:5px"></span></button>
</div>
```

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function popover() {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the desired lay-out that you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.popover{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left: 80% !important;

}

.popover .arrow{
    display:none;           
}
```

Adjust your needs

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/16/)**

Comment: thanks, I will play around with this and get it working :D

Comment: @BudaCristian: if you have found your answer, then why dont you  accepting it as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the following positions for popovers:

Left positioned popover:

```
data-placement="left"
```

Right positioned popover:

```
data-placement="right"
```

Top positioned popover:

```
data-placement="top"
```

Bottom positioned popover:

```
data-placement="bottom"
```

See: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Or change the CSS to

```
.popover{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left: 80% !important;
}

.popover .arrow{
    display:none;           
}
```

Comment: I know this, but is there something similar to a popover that can be far away from the button, in the corner?

Comment: Thanks, another question I have: Is it possible for the popover to get data from a html file? so to no be hardcoded in data-content="data here" but it to get the data from a html file (<h1>title</h1> <body>data here</body>)